# How to make bash autocomplete work in the middle of line?

Tags: bash, compgen

How to write autocomplete in bash, so that if I have:

```
mycommand first_argument|garbage
```

where `|` denotes the cursor, it should pass `"first_argument"` and not `"first_argumentgarbage"` to compgen?

In the examples I have it behaves in the wrong way

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "add remove list use current" -- "$cur") ) # buggy
```

Comment: As is, your example doesn't show anything. What do you mean by buggy ? have you sourced your completion script ? What is the content of `$cur` ? What does `echo ${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}` displays when you put it just before your `COMPREPLY` declaration ?

Comment: Press space, left, tab?

Comment: @Aserre: `cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}`. Since no space is at the cursor, of course it is first_argumentgarbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash completion uses a [lot of different variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html). Some of them are used to process input and determine which parameter to complete.

For the following explanation, I will use this test input (with `|` as the cursor) :

```
./test.sh ad re|garbage
```

- `${COMP_WORDS}` : contains all the words of the input in the form of an array. In this case, it contains : `${COMP_WORDS[@]} == {"./test.sh", "ad", "regarbage"}`

  - The word separator characters are found in the `$COMP_WORDBREAKS` variable
- `$COMP_CWORD` : contains the position of the word the cursor is curently selecting. In this case, it contains : `$COMP_CWORD == 2`
- `$COMP_LINE` : contains the whole input in form of string. In this case, it contains : `$COMP_LINE == "./test.sh ad regarbage"`
- `$COMP_POINT` : contains the position of the cursor in the whole line. In this case, it contains : `$COMP_POINT == 15`

Still using the same data, doing `cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}` will return the element at index 2 in the `${COMP_WORD}` array, which is `regarbage`.

To circumvent this behaviour, you'll have to play around with the `$COMP_LINE` and `$COMP_POINT` variables as well. Here is what I came up with :

```
# we truncate our line up to the position of our cursor
# we transform the result into an array
cur=(${COMP_LINE:0:$COMP_POINT})

# we use ${cur} the same way we would use ${COMP_WORDS}
COMPREPLY=( $( compgen -W "add remove list use current" -- "${cur[$COMP_CWORD]}" ) )
```

Output :

```
> ./test2.sh ad re|garbage
# press TAB
> ./test2.sh ad remove|garbage
```

Note that by default, there will be no space between `remove` and `garbage`. You'll have to play around the completion mechanics if this is a behaviour you want.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation. I knew most of the variables you mentioned, but I missed an elegant usage pattern, which you gave me with your last. Btw how is that `${cur[$COMP_CWORD]}` and `$cur[COMP_CWORD]}` both work?

Comment: The fact that `${cur[$COMP_CWORD]}` and `$cur[COMP_CWORD]` returns the same result is pure luck. You can read more about array dereferencing [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html).

Comment: I wouldn't call it pure luck. Mentioned page says it is something like putting the index inside `(( ))`: >The INDEXNR is treated as an arithmetic expression that must evaluate to a positive number.